# How can I display index in Htacess after a RewriteRule?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this rule in htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?$ producto-test.php?stock=$1 [QSA]
```

But when I access to

`http://www.example.com/`

Redirect automatic to

`http://www.example.com/?stock=`

I have 2 files: producto-test.php, index.php

Always access to producto-test.php with this configuration in htacess

What can i do to access: `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: The repetition is optional, try 1 or more times `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`

Comment: Just `+` instead of `*` in your rule so `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ producto-test.php?stock=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your quantifiers are optional in `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?$` so it can match an empty string and append that as `$1` in the url.

You can make the quantifier `+` for the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` or perhaps a bit shorter `[\w-]+`

See this page about the [L](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#page-header) flag as commented by anubhava if it should be the last processed rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ producto-test.php?stock=$1 [QSA,L]
```